# Use TLS v1.2 instead of v1.3

Tags: package-management, ssl

What package determines the version of TSL that a server uses? I have a game server that is using TLS v1.3 and yet the lobby/client does not deal well with that, there is a large delay (>10secs) on connection.
The lobby/client has no reason to upgrade yet so I need make it so the server uses TLS v1.2 but I don't know if it is simply a case of downgrading the apt package or if there is more involved.

I tried downgrading openssl

```
apt install openssl=1.1.0g-2ubuntu4
```

but it still uses TSLv1.3

```
[]# uname -a
Linux road-flag 4.15.0-74-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 08:06:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of a missconception. The TLS Version offered is not related to the package version. Also, to prevent clients from using a certain version of TLS, you need to tell the server application not to offer that TLS version to any given client.

Comment: the server is uberserver which uses twisted I believe. The client has the issue I think, but I would like it if the server could just adapt to the client

Comment: I just re-read your message, yes how do i do that? tell the server not to offer version v1.3

Comment: This depends on the application. I'm not familiar with "uberserver" or "twisted". Your best bet would be the documention offered by the vendor on how they handle SSL/TLS in their software.